# Obtener el nombre de las columnas de una tabla de sqlite con codigo c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

Quiero obtener el nombre de las columnas de la tabla que indico, obtuve el nombre de cada tabla con el siguiente comando:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select name from sqlite_master where type='table' order by name";
```

Pero ahora necesito el nombre de cada columna de las tablas que obtuve. Creo que encontre como hacerlo en android (no estoy seguro de que haga lo que ocupo), pero lo ocupo en codigo c# y no encuentro algun "equivalente" al codigo de android a c#.

```
 SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; (some code here...) mDataBase = getReadableDatabase(); Cursor dbCursor = mDataBase.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null); String[] columnNames = dbCursor.getColumnNames();
```

He conseguido conocer cuantas columnas tiene cada tabla con el siguiente codigo:

```
CommandText = string.Format("pragma table_info({0})", tableName);
```

No se si con eso puedo conseguir lo que estoy buscando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si revisas nuevamente el codigo del ejemplo de la consulta anterior

[SQLite Schema Class for VB.Net and C#](https://www.blakepell.com/2013-12-13-sqlite-schema-class-for-vbnet-and-csharp)

observaras que utiliza

```
    public List<SQLiteColumn> Columns(string tableName)
    {
        List<SQLiteColumn> lst = new List<SQLiteColumn>();
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = this.DbConnection.CreateCommand) {
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("pragma table_info({0})", tableName);
            SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader;
            while (dr.Read) {
                lst.Add(new SQLiteColumn(tableName, dr("type").ToString, Convert.ToInt32(dr("cid").ToString), dr("name").ToString, Convert.ToBoolean(dr("notnull").ToString), Convert.ToBoolean(dr("pk").ToString)));
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

como bien los describes usa el `pragma table_info({0})` pero ejecuta este en un `reader` iterando cada registro y obteniendo los datos de la columna, para eso defina una clase

```
public class SQLiteColumn
{
    public SQLiteColumn(string table, string type, int cId, string name, bool notNull, bool primaryKey)
    {
        this.Table = table;
        this.Type = type;
        this.CId = cId;
        this.Name = name;
        this.NotNull = notNull;
        this.PrimaryKey = primaryKey;
    }

    public SQLiteColumn()
    {
    }

    public string Table { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int CId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool NotNull { get; set; }
    public bool PrimaryKey { get; set; }
}
```

ya que son varios los atributos de la columna

Si querias algo mas simple que retorne solo los nombres podrias usar

```
public List<string> Columns(string tableName)
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();

    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = this.DbConnection.CreateCommand()) 
    {
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("pragma table_info({0})", tableName);
        SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read) {
            lst.Add(dr("name").ToString());
        }
    }

    return lst;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ayer cuando intentaba usar ese codigo lo aplique mal. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda compañero!

Answer (score 4):

Creo que llegué un poco tarde, pero tal vez este método te sirva:

```
SELECT name FROM pragma_table_info('[Nombre de la tabla]')
```

Esta linea es una consulta que podés hacerle al Sqlite que te devuelve el nombre de todas las columnas que lleva la tabla.
No es en C# pero quisa te sirva o a alguien más. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

esta consulta sql te devuelve los campos de una tabla en sqlite

```
SQL="SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('mi_tabla')"
```

los corchetes me dan error. gracias pór el aporte.